# How to sudo edit in Midnight Commander?

Tags: permissions, sudo, midnight-commander

I have the habit of running Midnight Commander as my normal user (so that I cannot cause too costly accidents).

Sometimes however I find that editing a configuration file in the system partition becomes desirable.

Neither with nano, nor with the internal mc editor can I save the file, since I don't have sudo privileges.

It would be nice if I could just sudo edit a file, without having to close / restart mc.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: You can drop into a shell from mc by pressing cntrl-o and then do `sudo nano filename`, then back to mc by cntrl-o after you edit. Is that good enough?

Comment: In all honesty, I was hoping for something more comfy ;) Nevertheless, this works. And what is nice is that I'm already in the corresponding directory, so no need to `cd`. Pretty close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`F9` to bring up the top menu > `Command` > `Edit menu file` > `User`. The menu file will open. Add

```
+ t r
e       Edit file with elevated priviledges
        xterm -e 'sudo vim %f' &
```

to it, separated by at least one blank line from the other code blocks already present in the file. Save and close the file. Now when you want to edit a file with priviledges, just press `F2` (brings up the user menu) and then `e` to select this entry.

---

`+ t r` guarantees that that entry only shows up for regular files (not for directories, sockets, etc.). See `man mc`, section `Edit Menu File` for more.

`xterm -e 'sudo vim %f' &` is the executed command. It launches a new terminal in the background with the editor — here Vim, choose the one you like best —, so that Midnight Commander does not block. The downside is that the password will be requested each time, no matter how small the interval between the sudos is. If you don't want that:

- Option 1: Simply use `sudo vim %f` instead, but that will take MC away from you until you close the editor.
- Option 2: Make a user entry similar to the one shown above, but one that launches a new MC with root permissions with `sudo mc %d %D &` (`%d %D` to make the new MC open in the directories that you are!). You can use a different color scheme for root so you remember to be cautious.

I really like option 2 because it is very convenient to move files around in protected directories such as `/usr` and `/etc`.

Comment: Apparently I do not have `xterm` installed, so I instead did `gnome-terminal -e` ... I guess it's a similar experience as it would have been with xterm. Opens a new terminal window asking for my password, then the editor. When exiting the editor, this new terminal window closes automatically.

Comment: I like this, quite fancy; the downside however is that _each time_ I edit, even if edits are just a few seconds apart, I need to re-type my password.

Comment: I have just re-read the last sentence, and turns out it's exactly what I was looking for. Leaving away the extra terminal instance, and having just `sudo nano %f` in the user menu keeps the same window as mc, so the sudo password is remembered (for a while, as configured), and also no need to resize/adjust the window. Very accepted :)

Comment: @Levente Glad to hear it was helpful! Note that gnome-terminal has deprecated `-e`, they recommend `--` instead now. I have also expanded a bit the answer with an option 2.

Comment: sudoedit? Or use $EDITOR? I like vim too (obviously), but there are surely easy ways to have this always do the right thing

Answer (score 4):

This method does not give direct `mc` functionality for the desired action, but you can drop into a shell from `mc` by pressing `cntrl-o` and then do `sudo nano [filename]`, then back to `mc` by `cntrl-o` after you are done editing.

Comment: The benefit I see with this one is that the sudo password is remembered for subsequent edits, for however long it is configured system wide; + the editor interface will "inherit" its dimensions and position from my mc window (no need to resize/adjust) (since it remains in the originally used window).

Comment: If the user has the command prompt set at the bottom line (as in `Options > Layout`), `ctrl-o` can be skipped. And I am almost sure MC has a keystroke to put the selected file in the command-line in that case, but I don't remember what it is ):